# JQuery validate within a Twitter Bootstrap modal with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate, modal-dialog

I'm working on a transport planner and in my tasks table I have a button to sign a routenumber to a task. When a task haven't got a routenumber at all, the button will call a bootstrap modal to assign a new routenumber to that task which will also be the standard routenumber.

When a task already has a routenumber, the button will call the **same** modal with a new checkbox added. Unchecked means, change the routenumber only today, checked means, make the inserted routenumber the standard routenumber.

I'm using JQuery for the validation but nothings happend and the form is submitted without validation. What am I doing wrong..?

**LINK TO CALL THE MODAL:**

```
<a href="#routenummer_view<?php echo $row['planning_id']; ?>" class="btn strong" data-toggle="modal"><?php if ($row['routenummer'] != ''){ echo $row['routenummer']; } if ($row['routenummer'] == ''){ ?><i class="icon-plus"></i><?php }?></a>
```

**MODAL:**

```
<div id="routenummer_view<?php echo $row['planning_id']?>" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="routenummer_viewLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <form class="modal-form" action="../includes/modals/routenummer/submit_view_routenummer.php"
        data-remote="true" method="post" id="routenummer_edit">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h3 id="routenummerviewLabel"><?php if ($row['routenummer'] == ''){ echo 'Standaard Routenummer Invoeren';} else echo 'Routenummer Wijzigen';?></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <label>Routenummer:</label> 
                <input type="text" name="routenummer" <?php if ($row['routenummer'] != NULL){ ?>value="<?php if ($row['routenummer'] != NULL){ echo $row['routenummer']; echo '" /><br />';}?> <?php } if ($row['routenummer'] == NULL){ ?> placeholder="Typ hier een routenummer..." /><?php if ($row['routenummer'] != NULL){ echo '<br />'; }}?>
                <?php if ($row['routenummer'] != NULL){ ?>
                 <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="standaard"> Maak standaard routenummer.</label>
                     <?php }?>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="hidden" name="opdrachtid" value="<?php echo $row['planning_id']; ?>" />
            <input type="submit" value="<?php if ($row['routenummer'] == ''){ echo 'Invoeren';} else echo 'Wijzigen';?>" class="btn btn-primary" />
            <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Annuleren</a>
        </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#routenummer_edit").validate({
        onkeyup : false,
        rules : {
            routenummer : {
                required : true,
                digits: true
            }
        },
        messages : {
            routenummer : {
                required : "Routenummer is verplicht.",
                digits : "Routenummer moet een getal zijn."
            }
        },
    });
});
```

**EXAMPLE IMAGE**
[image: Example image]

**EDIT**

**RENDERED HTML**

**When a task doesn't have a standard routenumber:**

```
<div id="routenummer_view90" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="routenummer_viewLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <form class="modal-form" action="../includes/modals/routenummer/submit_view_routenummer.php"
        data-remote="true" method="post" id="routenummer_edit">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h3 id="routenummerviewLabel">Standaard Routenummer Invoeren</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <label>Routenummer:</label> 
                <input type="text" name="routenummer"  placeholder="Typ hier een routenummer..." />                     
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="hidden" name="opdrachtid" value="90" />
            <input type="submit" value="Invoeren" class="btn btn-primary" />
            <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Annuleren</a>
        </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**When a task *does* have a standard routenumber:**

```
<div id="routenummer_view67" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="routenummer_viewLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <form class="modal-form" action="../includes/modals/routenummer/submit_view_routenummer.php"
        data-remote="true" method="post" id="routenummer_edit">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h3 id="routenummerviewLabel">Routenummer Wijzigen</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <label>Routenummer:</label> 
                <input type="text" name="routenummer" value="21" /><br />                                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="standaard"> Maak standaard routenummer.</label>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="hidden" name="opdrachtid" value="67" />
            <input type="submit" value="Wijzigen" class="btn btn-primary" />
            <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Annuleren</a>
        </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.modal-form').each(function () {
            $(this).validate({ // initialize the plugin
                rules: {
                    routenummer: {
                        required: true,
                        digits: true
                    }
                },
                messages : {
                    routenummer : {
                        required : "Routenummer is verplicht.",
                        digits : "Routenummer moet een getal zijn."
                    }
            }
        });
});
});
```

**EDIT**

**MODAL**

```
<div id="routenummer<?php echo $row['planning_id']?>" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="routenummerLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <form class="modal-form" action="../includes/modals/routenummer/submit_routenummer.php"
        data-remote="true" method="post">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h3 id="routenummerLabel"><?php if ($row['routenummer'] == ''){ echo 'Standaard Routenummer Invoeren';} else echo 'Routenummer Wijzigen';?></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <label>Routenummer:</label> 
                <input type="text" name="routenummer" <?php if ($row['routenummer'] != NULL){ ?>value="<?php if ($row['routenummer'] != NULL){ echo $row['routenummer']; echo '" /><br />';}?> <?php } if ($row['routenummer'] == NULL){ ?> placeholder="Typ hier een routenummer..." /><?php if ($row['routenummer'] != NULL){ echo '<br />'; }}?>
                <?php if ($row['routenummer'] != NULL){ ?>
                 <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="standaard"> Maak standaard routenummer.</label>
                     <?php }?>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="hidden" name="opdrachtid" value="<?php echo $row['planning_id']; ?>" />
            <input type="submit" value="<?php if ($row['routenummer'] == ''){ echo 'Invoeren';} else echo 'Wijzigen';?>" class="btn btn-primary" />
            <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Annuleren</a>
        </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hint:  The form **must** _already_ exist when you call `.validate()`.  Is the HTML for the modal and form on the same page where you call `.validate()`?  Do you create it dynamically as needed?  Do you bring it in with `ajax`?  You're going to have to make a single concise example showing us the _rendered_ HTML code.  Also show the jQuery that creates and opens the modal.  The raw PHP  means very little to solving this problem.  We fix your JavaScript and then you simply make your PHP comply with the solution.

Comment: The form already exists. For every task a modal is already created. The modals are unique by the planning_id. I have my JQuery in a .js file which is loaded. I don't use Ajax.. I've put the rendered code in my question.

Comment: Where is the jQuery that opens/closes the modal?  As long as the HTML for the form exists when `.validate()` is called, and the selector of `.validate()` matches the target `form`, it should work.

Comment: in the bootstrap.js..

Comment: Did you remember to properly include jQuery and the jQuery Validate script files?  Are you getting any JavaScript errors in your browser console?

Comment: I did.. Where do I check of there are any js errors? On the network/xhr tab in chrome?

Comment: Check for JavaScript errors in the Developer's Tools section of Chrome.  You might have to enable these in the preferences.

Comment: I've found it, but there are no errors..

Comment: I've shown you that your code is working.  How else can I help you?

Comment: I'll try some more.. In the fiddle it's working.. So I know that that my code is not the problem.. That already helped. Thank you!

Comment: Please don't forget to come back and let us know what you found and to accept an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that the modal-id is causing the problems?

Comment: I don't understand what the modal `id` has to do with anything.  `.validate()` is targeting your **form** `id`.

Comment: The problem is still not solved.. Could it be the problem is caused because every task has it's own modal (#routenummer<?php echo $row['planner_id'];?>) and that all that modals are loaded when the page is loaded? Even though all the modals have a different name, the form id is always the same (#routenummer_view).. Do I need variable validation rules as well? Like: "$("#routenummer_view **+ id**").validate({..."

Comment: Yes, if you have multiple `form` elements and they all have the same `ID`, that will certainly break it.  It's also invalid HTML... you can not have duplicate `id`'s on the page.

Comment: Do you have any idea what's the best way to fix this?

Comment: Get rid of all the duplicate `id`'s.  Then use a common `class` name instead.  To initialize them all at once, you also need a jQuery `.each()`.  Study this carefully:  http://jsfiddle.net/fEmrA/

Comment: I also added this to my answer below.

Comment: I'm also not understanding why you would have the same form duplicated multiple times.

Comment: Because my planner-table is in a While statement to use data form a database. The link to call to routenumber modal also. So I include my modal inside that while statement so I can use the database data (routenumber) inside that modal.

Comment: We're getting sidetracked, but anyway, did you get this fixed?

Comment: True. Unfortunately it is still not working. I've put my new Jquery in my question.. Ofcourse i've changed my form id into a class.

Comment: You are targeting `$('.routenummer')` in your new jQuery, but I do not see any class called `routenummer` on your `form` tag.  And until you remove any duplicate `id`'s on the page you will continue to have unpredictable problems.

Comment: Why not just target a `class` you already have?  `$('.modal-form').each(....`

Comment: I've added the (current) modal in my question. I'm targeting modal-form now in my jquery but still without succes...

Comment: But you are **not** targeting `.model-form` according to the code in your OP.  I really don't know how else to help you... I've already created multiple jsFiddle demonstrations showing working code.

Comment: I've editted my jquery in my question.. Still no success.. No javascript errors. I have a index page, where I include my planner-table and in that planner table I include the modals. Could that cause any problems? The modal and javascript looks ok now?

Comment: [Here is YOUR form code, duplicated FIVE times and it's working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/KJbtP/](http://jsfiddle.net/KJbtP/)  There are no duplicate `id`'s.  Based on this demo, there is nothing in your OP that would prevent this from working.  I'm going to stop responding in order to give you ample time to more carefully compare this last demo to your own page.  I'll also suggest that you create your own jsFiddle demo that shows your problem, instead of all this guess-work.

Comment: When I have the link to the modal inside the while statement and also the modal itself included in that while statement the validation fails, although the validation **is loaded** because the alert works. But, when I'm submitting an empty form, the success alert still pops up. When I put the link and the modal outside the While, everything works as it should. But then I can't use the id's in the link to the modal (<a href="#routenummer_view<?php echo $row['planning_id']; ?>"...) and in the modal itself <div id="routenummer_view<?php echo $row['planning_id']?>")

Comment: I know what the problem is. As said, I load a table with planner data from a database in a while statement, but ofcourse the </table>-tag is **outside** the while statement. But when I want to use db-data in the modal I have to include the modal in the while statement, so also inside the <table></table> tags which would be invalid html. Is there a way to pass the right db variables to the modal when the modal is outside the while statement?

Answer (score 1):

Validation is working as intended in both of your examples...

---

Your ***"When a task doesn't have a standard routenumber"*** example is working:

**http://jsfiddle.net/qdX8y/1/**

(Validation will not allow submission of an empty field)

---

Your ***"When a task does have a standard routenumber"*** example is also working.  However, [it passes validation immediately](http://jsfiddle.net/qdX8y/2/) because you already have a value in the field that meets the requirements of the compound rule, `required` and `digits`.

```
<input type="text" name="routenummer" value="21" />
```

Removing `value="21"` causes a validation message to be triggered.

**http://jsfiddle.net/qdX8y/**

---

**EDIT**:

As per comments on OP, it was discovered that the OP has multiple `form` elements sharing the same `id`.  Not only is this invalid HTML, but it breaks the Validate plugin since it does not know which `form` to target.

However, all `form` elements can share the same `class` name and then you can use a jQuery `.each()` to select them all.  This example contains five duplicate `<form>` elements, each with `class="myform"` and assumes all five `form` elements share the same `.validate()` options.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.myform').each(function () {
        $(this).validate({ // initialize the plugin on each form
            // your options and rules
        });
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/cWtd6/**

Comment: That's very strange.. When I leave the field empty I can still submit the form...?

Comment: Where?  My examples do not allow submission of an empty field.

Comment: @user2131419, but I only used _your_ code to make my working examples.  Check your links to your included script files.  Check for console errors.

Comment: In the fiddle it works.. When I use 'my own' code it doesn't. The links are ok.. Where can I see if there are any errors? Or maybe the problem is that all the modals for each task (different by the planning_id) are loaded already? I don't have a clue..